# Error "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send" when build docker image on azure pipelines

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

I am trying to build an base image on azure pipelines, but the connection is refused when pulling an installer form microsoft.

The Dockerfile, from [install dotnet samples](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/snippets/installing-dotnet.md):

```
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1607
RUN powershell -Command `
        $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; `
        $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; `
        Invoke-WebRequest `
            -UseBasicParsing `
            -Uri https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1 `
            -OutFile dotnet-install.ps1; `
        ./dotnet-install.ps1 `
            -InstallDir '/Program Files/dotnet' `
            -Channel 3.0 `
            -Runtime dotnet; `
        Remove-Item -Force dotnet-install.ps1 `
    && setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\dotnet"
```

The log:

```
##[section]Starting: Build an image
==============================================================================
Task         : Docker
Description  : Build or push Docker images, login or logout, or run a Docker command
Version      : 2.160.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker
==============================================================================
a2745d43-956f-4450-9ff4-25ef833410b3 exists true
[command]"C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe" build -f d:\a\8\s\Docker\Docker\wservercore-dotnetcore3.0.Dockerfile --label com.azure.dev.image.system.teamfoundationcollectionuri=https://dev.azure.com/SspCtt/ --label com.azure.dev.image.system.teamproject=GOD --label com.azure.dev.image.build.repository.name=GOD --label com.azure.dev.image.build.sourceversion=4 --label com.azure.dev.image.build.repository.uri=https://dev.azure.com/SspCtt/ --label com.azure.dev.image.build.sourcebranchname=GOD --label "com.azure.dev.image.build.definitionname=Build servicecore-dotnetcore3.0 image" --label com.azure.dev.image.build.buildnumber=20191204.4 --label com.azure.dev.image.build.builduri=vstfs:///Build/Build/4 -t dockerhub:4 d:\a\8\s\Docker\Docker
Sending build context to Docker daemon   2.56kB

Step 1/11 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1607
1607: Pulling from windows/servercore
3889bb8d808b: Already exists
57e8a97eaa75: Pulling fs layer
57e8a97eaa75: Verifying Checksum
57e8a97eaa75: Download complete
57e8a97eaa75: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:f5d4abf787650d742504be54e97f62874722b0747ad204108610dd25b2d66cd0
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1607
 ---> 5b0fdc7e6814
Step 2/11 : RUN powershell -Command         $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';         $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';         Invoke-WebRequest             -UseBasicParsing             -Uri https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1             -OutFile dotnet-install.ps1;         ./dotnet-install.ps1             -InstallDir '/Program Files/dotnet'             -Channel 3.0             -Runtime dotnet;         Remove-Item -Force dotnet-install.ps1     && setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\dotnet"
 ---> Running in 56585c5966de
[91mInvoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error 
[0m[91moccurred on a send.
At line:1 char:76
[0m[91m+ ... yContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri https://dot.net/v ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[0m[91m    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:Htt 
   pWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
[0m[91m    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShe 
   ll.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
[0m[91m 
[0mThe command 'cmd /S /C powershell -Command         $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';         $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';         Invoke-WebRequest             -UseBasicParsing             -Uri https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1             -OutFile dotnet-install.ps1;         ./dotnet-install.ps1             -InstallDir '/Program Files/dotnet'             -Channel 3.0             -Runtime dotnet;         Remove-Item -Force dotnet-install.ps1     && setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\dotnet"' returned a non-zero code: 1
##[error]The process 'C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[section]Finishing: Build an image
```

Comment: There is an Availability Degradation event for Azure DevOps services. See: https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/161664118 for details.This could be the cause of the error. Now the engineers have mitigated this event.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT Please post it as an answer so it helps others in the community who could have faced similar issues due to the incident. Thanks!

Comment: @MiguelSlv Please give it another try and check if the issue still persists.

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara-MSFT, still the same error.